# Inform the R package keras of the correct location of Python

Tags: python, r, keras

I installed `keras` and TensorFlow like this in R 3.3.3 Windows 64-bit:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_tensorflow()
```

At no point did it ask me for the location of Python. The correct location of Python is in my `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` as `D:/Python35/`.

However when I go to use `keras` functions like

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

It throws error messages saying that it can't find a DLL and giving a path in AppData to an old, removed copy of Anaconda Python.

> Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython,
>   config$pythonhome,  :
>   C:/Users/hackr/AppData/Local/CONTIN~1/ANACON~1/python35.dll - The
>   specified procedure could not be found.

How can I tell it the correct Python installation to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very well described [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html#providing-hints)

You can use:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("D:/Python35/")
```

And set the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` environment variable to `D:/Python35`.